# Draw and scale an external image

Tags: c#, wpf

I've found downloaded and converted into XAML some vertor picture:

```
        <Canvas Width="0" Height="0" ClipToBounds="True">
            <Path Fill="#FF000000" Stroke="#FF000000" StrokeMiterLimit="4" Name="path26">
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M51.688,5.25C46.261,5.1091 ... 51.344,83.125z" />
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
```

and now, i'd like to draw this picture on my custom drawing:

```
    private void Draw()
    {
        DrawingGroup aDrawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();

        for (int DrawingStage = 0; DrawingStage < 10; DrawingStage++)
        {
            GeometryDrawing drw = new GeometryDrawing();
            GeometryGroup gg = new GeometryGroup();

            if (DrawingStage == 1)
            {
                drw.Brush = Brushes.Beige;
                drw.Pen = new Pen(Brushes.LightGray, 0.01);

                RectangleGeometry myRectGeometry = new RectangleGeometry();
                myRectGeometry.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 3, 2.3);
                gg.Children.Add(myRectGeometry);
            }

            if (DrawingStage == 2)
            {
                drw.Pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 0.02);

                for (int i = 5; i < 16; i++)
                {
                    LineGeometry myRectGeometry = new LineGeometry(new Point(2.9, i * 0.1), new Point(0.1, i * 0.1));
                    gg.Children.Add(myRectGeometry);
                }

            }

            drw.Geometry = gg;
            aDrawingGroup.Children.Add(drw);
        }

        noteImage.Source = new DrawingImage(aDrawingGroup);
    }
```

How could i draw and scale this an external picture?

Comment: In code behind, you can parse a path geometry string with the [`Geometry.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Then you can add it to one of your GeometryGroups, optionally after setting its `Transform` property.